# How to use nested *Nested Dictionaries*

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So my code would look neatest if I were able to nest dictionaries. 
My questions are:

1. Are nested dictionaries a real thing? (Is it even possible?)
2. How do I set them up?
3. How do I get the value of a sub-dictionary key?

Here is some of the code that I am trying to use. Please tell me what the correct format is, and what might be wrong... Thanks!

```
Student.Alice = {
            Student.Alice.Math = {
                'math1'= 100
                'math2'= 98
                'math3' = 89
                'math4' = 91
                'math5' = 77
                'math6' = 90
                'math7' = 82
                'math8' = 100
                'math9' = 79
                'math10' = 100
                }
            Student.Alice.English = {
                'english1' = 100
                'english2' = 97
                'english3' = 98
                'english4' = 88
                'english5' = 94
                'english6' = 95
                'english7' = 98
                'english8' = 82
                'english9' = 84
                'english10' = 99
                }
            Student.Alice.Science = {
                'science1' = 78
                'science2' = 89
                'science3' = 88
                'science4' = 92
                'science5' = 92
                'science6' = 91
                'science7' = 93
                'science8' = 88
                'science9' = 99
                'science10' = 87
                }
            Student.Alice.French = {
                'french1' = 100
                'french2' = 100
                'french3' = 99
                'french4' = 104
                'french5' = 103
                'french6' = 97
                'french7' = 94
                'french8' = 93
                'french9' = 75
                'french10' = 93
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is `Student` is an class instance ?

Comment: Looking at this again, I think that it might look suspicious to people who don't know what I am trying to do. FYI: This is a hypothetical program for teachers to be able to do things with students' grades...

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner in python, could you explain what a class instance is? Nv mind, it is not a class instance

Comment: What is the type of the object `Student`? How does it look?

Comment: Student is just supposed to be part of the name of a dictionary. Do the dots do anything? I just added them for cleanliness...

Comment: You can't have dots in a variable name

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just ctrl h the dot out

Comment: Ohh, I see the problem with dots now.

Comment: Alice is a teacher and she teaches all those subjects and the grades are the grades of her students?

Comment: Ok, but then how do I call the value of any given key? Also, is a nested dictionary like the one above going to work?

Comment: no, alice is the student, and the grades listed are the ones she received (on tests or something)

Comment: Thx for the formatting change - kguest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested dictionaries are going to lead to a world of pain in the future. I highly suggest learning about object oriented programming, and `class`es. Below is a not-working-but-headed-in-the-right-direction example.

```
class Assignment(dict):
    '''This inherits from a dict, student will be the key, grade as the score'''
    def __init__(self, name, max_score):
        self.name = name
        self.max_score = max_score
        self.grades = {} # this will be used to store students and grades.

    def __getitem__(self, student):
        # we're overriding getitem, because the default is 0 if a student doesn't turn in their work
        if student in self:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, student)
        return 0.0

class GradeBook(dict):
    '''A gradebook is a dict of assignments'''
    def get_max_score(self):
        return sum(assignment.max_score for assignment in self.values())

    def get_percentage(self, student):
        return 100.0 * sum(assignment[student] for assignment in self.values()) / self.get_max_score()

class Course(object):
    def __init__(self, name, time, teacher, students):
        self.name = name
        self.time = time # can teach multiple courses with the same name, but not at the same time
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.students = students
        self.grade_book = GradeBook()

    def add_assignment(self, assignemnt):
        self.grade_book.append(assignment)

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {} {}>'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.first, self.last)


class Student(Person):
    '''A student is a person...'''


class Teacher(Person):
    '''A teacher is a person...'''
```

Answer (score 8):

1, 2) Yes, nested dictionaries are possible.

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 5}
e = {'a': 4, 'b': 7}
f = {'foo': d, 'bar': e}
```

3) You can access a sub dictionary element by

```
print f['bar']['a']
```

which would output `4`

So in your example you could have a dictionary called students, where each student has a dictionary of subjects, and each subject has a list of grades. Something like

```
students = {
    'Alice': {
        'Maths': [1, 56, 23, 56],
        'Science': [23, 53, 43],
        ...
    },
    'Bob': {
        'Maths': [1, 56, 23, 56],
        'Science': [23, 53, 43],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

To get Bob's second maths grade you would use `students['Bob']['Maths'][1]` (don't forget that list items start indexing at 0).

Comment: ok, but is it possible to have the dictionaries literally nested within eachother like they were in the question, or do I need to reformat the dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
students = {"Alice": {"Math":    [100, 98, 89, 91, 77, 90, 82, 100, 79, 100],
                      "English": [100, 97, 98, 88, 94, 95, 98, 82, 84, 99],
                      "Science": [78, 89, 88, 92, 92, 91, 93, 88, 99, 87],
                      "French":  [100, 100, 99, 104, 103, 97, 94, 93, 75, 93]
                      }
           }
```

Here, `students` is a dictionary, the keys of which are the student's name (only Alice is shown here, but you could add more). Each student is a dictionary whose keys are the subjects in which he or she is enrolled. The subjects are lists of scores. That is, rather than using a dictionary with keys such as `french3`, which are redundant because we already know they are the scores for French and we already know it is item #3 because it is the third item, we simply put them all in a list in sequence, and their order determines the index by which they are accessed. (Python list item numbers start with 0, which is slightly different than the original numbers, but it is straigtforward to adjust them if you want to display them numbered starting at 1.)

Now to calculate the total of Alice's Math scores, you could write:

```
sum(students["Alice"]["Math"])
```

Or to see all of Alice's scores:

```
print students["Alice"]
```

Or to see Alice's third French score:

```
print students["Alice"]["French"][2]
```

Just a note: it would probably be better to use a name other than `students` for the outer dictionary, since this is really a collection of *scores.* The student and subject levels are just there so you can specify which scores you want! So just `scores` or perhaps `student_scores` would be a better name.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `dict` that has strings as keys and `dict`s as values:

```
students = {"Alice": {"Math": [100, 98, 70], "English": [100, 97, 98]}}
```

Then you use it like: `students["Alice"]["English"][2]` - Alice's grade in the third test in English.

Comment: Same question as below:
"Is it possible to have the dictionaries literally nested within eachother like they were in the question, or do I need to reformat the dictionaries?"